# Obvious to/for you

Tags: prepositions

What's the difference between using *to* and *for* with an adjective to separate it from a pronoun?
I have found some similar questions about this topic, yet all those are not exactly about this concrete question.

1. Mother, the fact that cats are furry should be obvious to you.
2. Mother the fact that cats are furry should be obvious for you.

Answer (score 2):

[Obvious](https://m.freecollocation.com/browse/obvious) is generally followed by preposition ***to***.

> *PREP*. ***to*** *It is obvious to me that you're unhappy in your job.*

(Oxford Collocation Dictionary)

Answer (score 1):

In general, the word "to" is used with certain adjectives to specify the scope within which that adjective applies. So "agreeable to him," "useful to him," and, in this case, "obvious to him."

Comment: I agree, although I would suggest that "useful for him" has validity in some contexts. However I can't think of an occasion where I would say "obvious for him" or "agreeable for him". I think it's because obviousness and agreeableness are very much personal responses whereas usefulness can be assessed empirically.